# How to deal with imbalanced datasets in neural network trainning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imbalanced-data

I am even struggling to explain in a brief but clear way my question, so I'll do my best effort to provide some background information before jumping directly into the question.

**Brackground**

I have a very imbalanced dataset that has 3 classes, which 2 of them are the minority classes and I'm interested in classify them.

The dataset is composed by sparse features and looks like this:

```
RA0 RA1 RA2 RA3 RA4 RA5 RA6 RA7 RA8 RA9 ... RB1 RB2 RB3 RB4 RB5 RB6 RB7 RB8 RB9 label
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  2
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  1
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  1
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  1
```

This dataset is very imbalaced, as the value_counts for the labels is as follows:

```
df.label.value_counts()/len(df)
>0    0.944352
>1    0.028622
>2    0.027025
```

The `RAX` features corresponds to label 1 and the `RBX` features corresponds to label 2. Why are those two labels "mixed" with those two different type of features? The original data is a time series and the labels represent a "state" of the timeseries.

So, I tried over and under sampling methods to try to "rebalance" the dataset, but what seemed to work better in this case was to trying to find out the `class_weights` of the labels by using a GridSearch.

I tried to do a GridSearch using a `roc_auc` scoring and then trainning of a neural network to do the classification, but I am struggling with the metrics part. The model is as follows:

```
 import tensorflow as tf

 def seq_model(n_features=20,init_neurons=170,decay=0.25,layers=3,lr=0.0001,activation1 = 'relu',activation2='relu'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(n_features, input_dim=n_features, activation=activation1))
    actual_neurons = init_neurons
    for i in range(layers):
        actual_neurons = int(actual_neurons*(1-decay*i))
        if actual_neurons <=0:
            break
        model.add(Dense(actual_neurons,activation = activation2))
    model.add(Dense(3,activation = 'softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
    return model
```

And after running a `GridSearch`, I got that the best class_weights for this dataset was `{0: 1, 1: 95, 2: 95}`. Then, after doing the `GridSearch` I trainned the model, but I noticed that `Keras` does not supports anymore `roc_auc` curve for metrics (like `accuracy`), so reading other questions and answers in SO, I ended up with this:

```
class RocCallBack(Callback):
    def __init__(self,training_data,validation_data):
        self.x = training_data[0]
        self.y = training_data[1]
        self.x_val = validation_data[0]
        self.y_val = validation_data[1]
        
    def on_train_begin(self,logs={}):
        return
    def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
        return
    
    def on_epoch_begin(self,epoch,logs={}):
        return
    
    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,logs={}):
        y_pred_train = self.model.predict_proba(self.x)
        roc_train = roc_auc_score(self.y,y_pred_train)
        y_pred_val = self.model.predict_proba(self.x_val)
        roc_val = roc_auc_score(self.y_val,y_pred_val)
        print('\rroc-auc_train: %s - roc-auc_val: %s' % (str(round(roc_train,4)),str(round(roc_val,4))),end=100*' '+'\n')
        return
    
    def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        return

roc = RocCallBack(training_data=(x_train.values,y_train2),
                 validation_data = (x_test.values,y_test2))

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience = 100,verbose = True,monitor='val_auc',restore_best_weights=True)
check_point = ModelCheckpoint('classifier.hdf5',verbose=1,save_best_only=True,monitor = 'val_auc')

y_train2 = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test2 = to_categorical(y_test)

history = model.fit(x_train.values,y_train2, 
                    epochs = 50000,
                    batch_size = 24,
                    validation_data=(x_test.values,y_test2),
                    shuffle = False,
                    class_weight={0: 1, 1: 95, 2: 95},
                   callbacks=[roc,early_stopping,check_point])
```

**Questions**:

a) When training, I noticed that the model was trying to minimize the `val_auc` value, which I was not expecting, because I thought that the idea was to maximize it. Is this normal or I did some mistake in the process?

b) In order to optimize the `roc_auc` (and therefore increase the precision, right?) it is correct to put `tf.keras.metrics.AUC()` in the model as a metric? If not, how should it be done to achieve a good performance?

c) When finding optimal weights for the classes, I should not use `accuracy` as a metric, right? Is `roc_auc` the best metric I could use for this cases?

I'm really sorry if this was a long post, but I'm still learning how to deal with this type of datasets and any help is appreciated. I can also provide any other information if needed.

Comment: Standard ways of dealing w. imbalanced datasets is subsampling, oversampling or synthetic samples. For imbalanced you are correct, accuracy is bad. Use a different metric that takes the cost into account

Comment: @IanQuah Thanks for your reply. I did tried under and over sampling, but did not get very good results. I did tried them with accuracy as a metric tho. Or I should use, for example, over sampling + class weight + roc auc? Which other metric would you recommend me?

Comment: Accuracy is a bad metric. If you have 99% class A and you always guess "A", your accuracy is 99% but that's not a good result. I'd just google imbalanced class losses